# I had bitcoin via Changetip but it closed and I transferred coin to a wallet which I don't remember.

Tags: client

I have bitcoin via Changetip but Changetip website closed and I transferred coin to a wallet which I don't remember. My question is how do I retrieve my bitcoin? Any help is appreciated, thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to remember what wallet you used to clear out your change tip account. Without that wallet, you'll be unable to recover/spend those bitcoins. Try searching your email, browsing history, etc, for clues as to what wallet you used. Best of luck.